# jquery changing innerhtml of a P isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what I thought was a simple select with jQuery to change some text on a paragraph. It works perfect the traditional way i.e.

```
document.getElementById('message_text').innerHTML = "hello";
```

But with jQuery it doesn't. I have checked the values of `$('#message_text')` and sure enough I see the items.

```
$('#message_text').innerHTML = "hello";
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you do something like `$('#message_text')` what you have there is not a regular DOM object, but a jQuery wrapped set (even though in this case it'd only be one element.) If you wanted to access a particular DOM property, you could do this:

```
$('#message_text')[0].innerHTML = 'whatever';
$('#message_text').get(0).innerHTML = 'whatever';
```

However, this isn't necessary in this case as jQuery has two functions to do what you want:

[`html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Html):

```
$('#message_text').html('whatever');
```

[`text()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text):

```
$('#message_text').text('whatever');
```

The difference between the two is that `html()` will allow HTML while `text()` will escape any HTML tags you pass to it. Use the one you need over manually manipulating the HTML with innerHTML.

Comment: Nice of you to give a full explanation, I deleted my simpler, non-explanatory answer, since yours is better.

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery function [`$()`](http://docs.jquery.com/%24) is not returning a *HTMLElement* object like `getElementById()` does but a *jQuery* object. And there you just have the [`html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Html) method as equivalent to `innerHTML`. So:

```
$('#message_text').html('hello');
```

Answer (score 5):

`$('#message_text').html('hello')`

jQuery selector returns an array, not a DOM Element node.