# Add / Substract Number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this working to add/minus a number in the input field.

However, I want the result to be display in `<p class="qty1"></p>` and not in the `input` field.

I tried to get it done myself using `innerHTML` but couldn't get it to work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('.form-height').find('.qty'),
    currentVal = parseInt($qty.val()),
    isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    !isNaN(currentVal) && $qty.val(
    isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal)
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-height">
  <input id="qty1" type="text" readonly value="5" class="qty form-control" />
  <p class="qty1"></p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-height">
  <input id="qty2" type="text" readonly value="7" class="qty form-control" />
  <p class="qty2"></p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935956/jquery-changing-innerhtml-of-a-p-isnt-working

Comment: Ankush <p> tag has class and input has Id which is considerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code should do what you want:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('.form-height').find('.qty'),
    currentVal = parseInt($qty.val()),
    isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        newVal = isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal);
        $p.text(newVal);
        $qty.val(newVal);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-height">
  <input id="qty1" type="text" readonly value="5" class="qty form-control" />
  <p class="qty1"></p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-height">
  <input id="qty2" type="text" readonly value="7" class="qty form-control" />
  <p class="qty2"></p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
```

**Edit** If the `<input>` tag is to be completely deleted, then it only requires a minor modification to your code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('.form-height').find('.qty'),
    currentVal = parseInt($qty.text()),
    isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    !isNaN(currentVal) && $qty.text(
    isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal)
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-height">
  <p class="qty">5</p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
<hr />
<div class="form-height">
  <p class="qty">7</p>
  <img src="images/minus.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <img id="add1" src="images/plus.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .html() or .text() to append the value to p tag like

```
$('.qty1').html(currentValue);
```

OR

```
$('.qty1').text(currentValue);
```

To know the difference between two methods [Click here](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/02/difference-between-jquery-text-and-html.html)